# Remove the attribute programmatically in magento2?

Tags: magento2.3, php-7.2

I want delete the existing attribute called Manufacturer. Check if this attribute exists before deleting.

How to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

In order to check and remove attribute

```
if(!$setup->getAttributeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'attribute_code')) {
       $eav_setup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'attribute_code');                                                        
}
```

Complete code on InstallData.php

```
<?php                                                         
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;                                      
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;                              
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;                   
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;                 
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;             
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface{
 private $eav_setup_factory;

public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eav_setup_factory)
{
    $this->eav_setup_factory = $eav_setup_factory;
}

public function install(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
    ModuleContextInterface $context
) {
    $eav_setup = $this->eav_setup_factory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    if(!$setup->getAttributeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'attribute_code')) {
         $eav_setup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'attribute_code');
    }
    $eav_setup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'attribute_code',
        [
            'type'          => 'varchar',
            'frontend'      => '',
            'label'         => 'Allowed Customer Group',
            'input'         => 'multiselect',
            'class'         => '',
            'attribute_set' => 'Default',
            'global'        => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'visible'       => true,
            'required'      => false,
            'user_defined'  => true,
            'default'       => null,
            'searchable'    => false,
            'filterable'    => false,
            'comparable'    => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique'        => false,
            'apply_to'      => '',
            'system'        => 1,
            'group'         => 'Attributes List'
        ]
    );
    //add product attribute to existing attribute_sets
    $entity_type_id = $eav_setup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
    $attribute_set_ids = $eav_setup->getAllAttributeSetIds($entity_type_id);
    foreach ($attribute_set_ids as $attribute_set_id) {
        $group_id = $eav_setup->getAttributeGroupId($entity_type_id, $attribute_set_id, "group_name");
        $eav_setup->addAttributeToGroup(
            $entity_type_id,
            $attribute_set_id,
            $group_id,
            'attribute_name',
            20
        );
    }
}}
```

> NOTE : If you have module exist already do the same via **UpgradeData.php**

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This method compare to the other method also works for system attributes.

Comment: should be if($setup->getAttributeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'attribute_code'))

Comment: It was check if "attribute_code" exists, then remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface`,you can delete an attribute

it has `delete()` method which can able to delete the attribute.

***Here the code: i  assume that attribute entity type is product and attribute code is `manufacturer`***

```
<?php
namespace {NameSpace};

class {ClassName} {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $attributeRepository;

    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository
    ) {

        $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
    }
    public function deleteAttibute()
    {
        $entityTypeCode = \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY;
        $attributeCode = 'manufacturer';

        try{
            $attributeData = $this->attributeRepository->get($entityTypeCode, $attributeCode);
            $this->attributeRepository->delete($attributeData);

            // goto catch when attribute does not exits
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $ex) {
            // // goto catch of type StateException when getting error on Delete
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException $ex) {

        }

    }
}
```