# Magento2 getting error after removing/deleting custom module

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

Magento2 getting error after removing custom module. In this module I have created a custom customer attribute.

```
ERROR: Class Test\Test\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\TestAttribute does not exist [] []
```

Can someone guide me on proper way to remove this module?

Comment: check that module has install any product, category, or customer Attribute. Please check and update me.

Comment: Custom customer attribute

Answer (score 0):

> **Below File is for remove Custom Attribute**

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

$serviceLocator = new \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager();
$serviceLocator->setService(\Magento\Setup\Mvc\Bootstrap\InitParamListener::BOOTSTRAP_PARAM, []);

$provider = new \Magento\Setup\Model\ObjectManagerProvider($serviceLocator);

$dataSetupFactory = new \Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetupFactory($provider);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface | \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup */
$setup = $dataSetupFactory->create();
$eavSetupFactory = new \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory($obj);
$eavSetup = $eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);


// For Remove Customer Attribute
$eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'ATTRIBUTE_CODE');

// For Remove Product Attribute
$eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'ATTRIBUTE_CODE');

// For Remove Category Attribute
$eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'ATTRIBUTE_CODE');
```

[Reference](https://www.codealist.com/magento-remove-attribute-programmatically/)

Comment: This file needs to run from root, right? I need to uninstall the custom customer attribute when user uninstalls the module

Comment: You need to create Uninstall.php file please check link https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-how-to-create-sql-setup-script.html#uninstall-script

Comment: I created the uninstalled script & run module;uninstall cmd but getting following error module is not an installed composer package

Comment: First Install module and after run module;uninstall  cmd

Comment: Followed that still getting same error

Comment: Share your SetUp Folder Files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127567/discussion-between-arjun-and-msquare).

Answer (score 0):

Just run the below Mysql query, it will show you which eav_attribute is using the deleted source class.

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `source_model` LIKE '%TestAttribute%'
```

If it is showing an attribute, you need to remove this attribute or set the source_model as NULL.

For removing attributes follow the below answer.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/144622/36463

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I am aware about deleting using quesry. how can I deleted via uninstall.php script if I haven't uploaded module in packagelist?

Comment: Got it. In that case, we can use a custom temporary controller or custom CLI script to delete the attribute. Please refer this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/263826/36463

Comment: CLI i got it but using custom temporary controller. How can i achive this? zlet say even if I create a temp controller where eam I suppose to call it as I need to delete this attributes when some one deletes module manually.

Comment: If you don't want to create a custom controller or CLI, then try Magento 2 REST API to delete the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the way I did, might help someone

```
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class UninstallPaymentMethod extends Command
{
    const SETUP_MODULE = 'setup_module';
    protected $eavSetupFactory;
    private $state;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
    )
    {
        parent::__construct('my:first:command');
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        $this->state = $state;
    }

   protected function configure()
   {
       $this->setName('uninstallpaymentmethod:test');
       $this->setDescription('Removing custom customer attribute entry & setup module entry');
       
       parent::configure();
   }
   protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
   {    $this->state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND);
       try {

        $connection  = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $tableName = $connection->getTableName(self::SETUP_MODULE);

        $whereConditions = [
          $connection->quoteInto('module = ?','Test_Test'),
        ];


        $connection->delete($tableName, $whereConditions);

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();

        $entityTypeId = 1; // Find these in the eav_entity_type table
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute($entityTypeId, 'test1');
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute($entityTypeId, 'test2');

        $output->writeln("Removed module attributes successfully.");

       } catch (Exception $e) {
           $output->writeln("There was some issue in removing attibute.");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: try this code https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/341574/82670