# Magento2 error In State.php line 153: Area code is not set

Tags: magento2, command, console

I have created a custom command, when I run upgrade command to install that module getting following error

> In State.php line 153:    Area code is not set

Following is my code

```
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class UninstallPaymentMethod extends Command
{
    const SETUP_MODULE = 'setup_module';
    protected $eavSetupFactory;
    private $state;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
    )
    {
        parent::__construct('my:first:command');
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        $this->state = $state;
    }

   protected function configure()
   {
       $this->setName('uninstallpaymentmethod:test');
       $this->setDescription('Removing custom customer attribute entry & setup module entry');
       
       parent::configure();
   }
   protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
   {    $this->state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND);
       try {

        $connection  = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $tableName = $connection->getTableName(self::SETUP_MODULE);

        $whereConditions = [
          $connection->quoteInto('module = ?','Test_Test'),
        ];


        $connection->delete($tableName, $whereConditions);

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();

        $entityTypeId = 1; // Find these in the eav_entity_type table
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute($entityTypeId, 'test1');
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute($entityTypeId, 'test2');

        $output->writeln("Removed module attributes successfully.");

       } catch (Exception $e) {
           $output->writeln("There was some issue in removing attibute.");
       }
   }
}
```

Can someone guide me on where am I wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Please response this answer  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/341337/82670

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this code**

```
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class UninstallPaymentMethod extends Command
{

    const SETUP_MODULE = 'setup_module';
    protected $eavSetupFactory;
    private $state;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
    ) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        $this->setup = $setup;
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('uninstallpaymentmethod:test');
        $this->setDescription('Removing custom customer attribute entry & setup module entry');

        parent::configure();
    }
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        try {

            $this->setup->startSetup();

            $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
            $tableName = $connection->getTableName(self::SETUP_MODULE);

            $whereConditions = [
                $connection->quoteInto('module = ?', 'VendoreName_ModuleName'),
            ];

            $connection->delete($tableName, $whereConditions);

            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();

            // For Remove Customer Attribute
            $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'ATTRIBUTE_CODE');

            // For Remove Product Attribute
            $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'ATTRIBUTE_CODE');

            // For Remove Category Attribute
            $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'ATTRIBUTE_CODE');

            $this->setup->endSetup();

            $output->writeln("Removed module attributes successfully.");

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $output->writeln("There was some issue in removing attibute.");
        }
    }
}
```

> **Run Magento 2 commands**

**php bin/magento module:disable VendoreName_ModuleName**

**php bin/magento uninstallpaymentmethod:test**

**php bin/magento s:up**

Comment: Thanks for providing ans. I already got a solution by trying different things

Answer (score 0):

```
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class UninstallPaymentMethod extends Command
{
    const SETUP_MODULE = 'setup_module';
    protected $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
    )
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
    }

   protected function configure()
   {
       $this->setName('uninstallpaymentmethod:test');
       $this->setDescription('Removing custom customer attribute entry & setup module entry');
       
       parent::configure();
   }
   protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
   {   
       try {

        $connection  = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $tableName = $connection->getTableName(self::SETUP_MODULE);

        $whereConditions = [
          $connection->quoteInto('module = ?','Test_Test'),
        ];


        $connection->delete($tableName, $whereConditions);

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();

        $entityTypeId = 1; // Find these in the eav_entity_type table
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute($entityTypeId, 'test1');
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute($entityTypeId, 'test2');

        $output->writeln("Removed module attributes successfully.");

       } catch (Exception $e) {
           $output->writeln("There was some issue in removing attibute.");
       }
   }
}
```

This worked for me.